# How to start SharePoint Workflow programmatically using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, csom, workflow-manager

I am trying to start share-point workflow using CSOM(Client side object model) by following means of code. But i got the following error from the line mark in comment. Please help me to figure out this error.

> **Error :-** *Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null
>   object. Object returned by the following call stack is null.
>   "GetWorkflowDeploymentService new
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager() "*

```
 public bool StartWorkFlow()
 {

   string workflowName = "UpdateDealStatus";

   // connect to the workflow services via a CSOM client context
   var workflowServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(_sharepoint,                  _sharepoint.Web);

  // connect to the deployment service
   var workflowDeploymentService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();

  // get all installed workflows
  var publishedWorkflowDefinitions =    workflowDeploymentService.EnumerateDefinitions(true);
            _sharepoint.Load(publishedWorkflowDefinitions);

   try
   {
      _sharepoint.ExecuteQuery();//Error thrown from this line
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {


   }

   // find the first workflow definition
   var firstWorkflowDefinition = publishedWorkflowDefinitions.First();

   // connect to the subscription service
   var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();

   // get all workflow associations
   var workflowAssociations = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByDefinition(firstWorkflowDefinition.Id);

   _sharepoint.Load(workflowAssociations);
   _sharepoint.ExecuteQuery();

   foreach (var association in workflowAssociations)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",
       association.Id, association.Name);
   }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: any luck with solving this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(loginId, passWord);

var workflowServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(ctx, ctx.Web);
var workflowInteropService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInteropService();
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var workflowDeploymentService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();

var publishedWorkflowDefinitions = workflowDeploymentService.EnumerateDefinitions(true);
ctx.Load(publishedWorkflowDefinitions);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var def = from defs in publishedWorkflowDefinitions
          where defs.DisplayName == workflowName
          select defs;

WorkflowDefinition workflow = def.FirstOrDefault();

if(workflow != null) 
{ 
    // get all workflow associations
    var workflowAssociations = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByDefinition(workflow.Id);
    ctx.Load(workflowAssociations);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // find the first association
    var firstWorkflowAssociation = workflowAssociations.First();

    // start the workflow
    var startParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    if (ctx.Web.ListExists(listName)) {
        List list = ctx.Web.GetListByTitle(listName);

        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query).
        ctx.Load(items);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items) {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting workflow for item: " + listItem.Id);
            workflowInstanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem(firstWorkflowAssociation, listItem.Id, startParameters);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Complete reference: [Here](https://msftplayground.com/2015/08/starting-a-workflow-with-csom/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look at example below:

```
 public class WorkflowRepository 
    {
        private InteropService _interopService;
        private WorkflowInstanceService _instanceService;
        private WorkflowSubscriptionCollection _subscriptions;
        public ClientContext Context;

        public WorkflowRepository(ClientContext clientContext) 
        {
            Context          = clientContext;
            var wfMngr       = new WorkflowServicesManager(Context, Context.Web);
            var subsrService = wfMngr.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
            _interopService  = wfMngr.GetWorkflowInteropService();
            _instanceService = wfMngr.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
            _subscriptions   = subsrService.EnumerateSubscriptions();

            Context.Load(_subscriptions);
            Context.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        #region basic methods 
        public Guid RunSiteWorkflow45(string wfName, IDictionary<string, object> payload)
        {
            var subscription = _subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(sub => sub.Name == wfName);
            var wf = _instanceService.StartWorkflow(subscription, payload);

            Context.ExecuteQuery();
            return wf.Value;
        }

        public Guid RunListWorkflow45(string list, int itemId, string wfName, IDictionary<string, object> payload)
        {
            var subscription = _subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(sub => sub.Name == wfName);
            if (payload == null) //StartWorkflowOnListItem will throw exception if null
                payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            var wf = _instanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemId, payload);

            Context.ExecuteQuery();
            return wf.Value;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```