# How to start a "Workflow 2010" with CSOM in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, spservices, send-email

I am creating a workflow that sends an email to internal & **external** users.
Since, in sharepoint Online, workflows are not allowed to send emails to external users. It is not the case in "workflow 2010", so I created a "workflow **2010**" and attached it to the site collection through "Sharepoint Designer 2013".

[image: Here is my workflow "SendEmail"]

Now here is my **SendEmail** workflow, is there a way I could start this workflow from my **Sharepoint Addin (Office 365)** i.e JavaScript solution

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to my answer in similar **[:thread:](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138662/how-to-start-sharepoint-workflow-programmatically-using-csom/221027#221027)**

Answer (score 2):

## JSOM

[Start SharePoint Workflows with JavaScript Client Object Model](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/08/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html)

```
function LoadScripts(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext" , function(){
        SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.workflowservices.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.workflowservices.js'));
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.workflowservices.js', "SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager", StartSiteWorkflow);
    })    
}

function StartSiteWorkflow(){

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            
    var web = context.get_web();
                
    //Workflow Services Manager
    var wfServicesManager = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(context, web);
                
    //Workflow Interop Service used to interact with SharePoint 2010 Engine Workflows
    var interopService = wfServicesManager.getWorkflowInteropService()
                
    //Initiation Parameters have to be in a plain JS Object.
    var initiationParameters = {
        FirstName: "Vardhaman",
        LastName: "Deshpande"
    };
                
    //Start the Site Workflow by Passing the name of the Workflow and the initiation Parameters.
    interopService.startWorkflow("My Workflow", null, null, null, initiationParameters);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("workflow started");
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    LoadScripts();
});
```

**C#**

[Follow my paste bin](http://pastebin.com/XaSidfuE)

Comment: Just a note: this solution won't work for any SharePoint 2010 workflows using assignment stages parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to update the Assign To field that is in Approval/Collect Feedback Workflows with this solution?  I tried to assign a person by setting AssignedToId to the id of the person I wanted to assign the workflow task to in the initiationParameters but the workflow was kicked off without being assigned to anyone.

Comment: I have not try that yet but I believe there should be a way. @James11

Comment: I agree, it seems like my problem is I can't figure out how to get the workflow to recognize a Person/Group initiation Parameter.  If I try to use the persons name or email it just recognizes it as a string, and if I try to use the Id it just recognizes it as a number.  Trying to set the Reviewer or Approver as a  SP.Data.UserInfoItem object doesn't work either, in that case the parameter appears to get completely removed from the XML request that is generated for SharePoint.