# How to trigger sharepoint workflow in office 365 programatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

How to trigger sharepoint designer workflow in office 365. the below code works fine in Onprmises. I want it in sharepoint office 365

```
 public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

       base.ItemAdded(properties);
        if (properties.ListItem.ParentList.TemplateFeatureId == new Guid("00afea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b260101"))
        {
            SPWorkflowManager wfManager = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.WorkflowManager;
            SPWorkflowAssociationCollection wfassociationCollection = properties.ListItem.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations;
            foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation wfAssociation in wfassociationCollection)
            {

                if ((wfAssociation.BaseId == new Guid("4b6900a0-2f1b-45ff-b7b5-498684cc09bc")))
                {
                    //f489e44f-5ffb-4941-9f88-611ecf3b6b6d dfaba5c5-5e6a-4a84-8b4d-633702a887cb
                    wfManager.StartWorkflow(properties.ListItem, wfAssociation, wfAssociation.AssociationData, true);
                    break;
                }

            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using list event receiver and triggering the workflow in that event receiver. this is fine for On premise.
But for office 365 you don't have direct event receiver like On premises.
So you have to know how to create Remote event receiver for Office 365 and then how to trigger the workflow in remote event receiver.

1. See the below post to create remote event receiver for lists

https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/sharepoint-2013-how-to-develop-remote-event-receivers-for-list-and-list-item-events/

2. trigger the workflow using CSOM use this forum and copy the code in remove event receiver created in above post

[How to start SharePoint Workflow programmatically using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138662/how-to-start-sharepoint-workflow-programmatically-using-csom)

3. you should know how to deploy the Provided hosted app and the deploying the service in web site present in the solution on microsoft azure portal

you also look at this provide hosted app code sample on how to trigger workflow in remote event receivers

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Call-a-f5d247db