# cannot get workflow deployment service in 2013 csom

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

My problem is exactly described in the question below, but has no accepted, or helpful answer.

Most answers mention Office 365, which might work, but I am looking at a 2013 setup.

[How to start SharePoint Workflow programmatically using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138662/how-to-start-sharepoint-workflow-programmatically-using-csom)

I'm running on SP Server 2013 and trying to do some workflow operations through CSOM but I keep getting null at the GetWorkflowDeploymentService call

```
WorkflowDeploymentService workflowDeploymentService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();
```

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException:
>   Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object
>   returned by the following call stack is null.
>   "GetWorkflowDeploymentService new
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager() "

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permissions issue, 
try changing the user permissions to design on both site and site collection

Comment: account is site collection administrator